# Multiple values grouped by an attribute in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

So I don't know if what I'm trying to do is achievable and I'll try to explain as best as I can. So, I have a table [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaYmL.png) on the Query Editor

At lines 4 and 5 there are, at the second column, which contains weight infos, the number 3065 which I got after unmerging the last column and splitting their valus into two coolums with different attributes and then unpivoting them into attributes which are listed on the third column. My issue is, when I unmerge, the weight gets duplicated and when I try to use a table visual on Power BI, I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ChWz1.png).

As you can see, both the infos at the 4th and 5th rows on the "Valor" column comes from the same RNC number, but they end up getting split after I unmerge them and the weights end up getting duplicate, screwing up the total sum. What I need is something that would look like this:
[Where the same weight is applied to two rows and count as only one info instead of getting duplicated and accounted for two times.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnNVu.jpg)

So, in summary, I need the same info to be applied to more than one row and not be subject to sum more than once, just like if I was to merge cells on Excel and use the sum function, where it would only just sum once the value on the multiple merged cells.

I tried the following table which almost got what I want, wbut while the weight sum is right, now the problem is that if I have two OP numbers for the same RNC number, I can just filter the visual by one of them:

```
Test Table = 
VAR _tempTable = 
SUMMARIZE(
    'RNC Testes - Sheet1',
    'RNC Testes - Sheet1'[n° RNC],
    "Peso",MAX('RNC Testes - Sheet1'[Peso (kg)]),
    "OP",MAX('RNC Testes - Sheet1'[Valor]),
    "Todas OPs",MAX('RNC Testes - Sheet1'[Mesclado]),
    "Atributo",MAX('RNC Testes - Sheet1'[Atributo])
    )
RETURN _tempTable
```

[Smaller OP number not showing on the filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu5DH.png).